# Brightness automatically increases in my Ubuntu even I don't want it to

Tags: brightness

While working on my laptop I saw that my brightness automatically increases and become full. I tried to use the adaptive brightness option but it was unable for my laptop. Can u plzz fix it.
I have recently switched to ubuntu 20.04 and problem started after few days of installation.
I am using Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series.
Whenever I press some random keys from keyboard the brightness automatically increases to full.
f11 key is working properly which is used to lower the brightness but f12 key is not working which is used to increase brightness

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1366865/edit) your question and let us know which version of Ubuntu you are using, what is your laptop model, and also, whether this issue is present since the installation or it came up recently. Do not add these information to the comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: please give some solution.

Comment: Can you reboot and boot with an older kernel (go to advanced options in grub menu), and check if the issue is present there?

Comment: I tried that but another issue came up while I was working on chrome the Inspect element tab automatically opened. I think brightness issue is solved as it didn't showed up till now

Comment: The shortcut for inspect element is also F12. I believe there is some issue with your keyboard (maybe some local short circuit due to dust accumulation), and F12 is sending ghost signals.

Comment: Thank you for your help